# Add a new action in Mage_XmlConnect to generate a new url

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller, controller

I’m trying to use the Mage_XmlConnect module to build my mobile app.

Simply I need to develop a module (or modify the Xmlconnect one) that calling a defined URL return to me XML data.

The module Mage_XmlConnect provides some URLs which returns magento data in XML format: 
for example the URL 
http://www.mydomain.com/xmlconnect/catalog/category/id/13

returns products from the category with id 13.

How can I modify the XmlConnect module to get some XML data at http://www.mydomain.com/xmlconnect/catalog/stock

I saw there is a categoryAction() method in /app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/controllers/CatalogController.php 
and I foolishly thought I can reach my result adding a new method stockAction(), instead a get only a 404 page.

Thanks

P.S. 
Using the URLs i provide above in your domains you’ll get an error cause you need some other call before to get it work.
My question is for general pourpose

Comment: It's unclear that you're asking here.

Comment: I edit the question and I try to be more clear. I only need to know how to modify the controller to get the new URL works. Which data must the page displays is not a problem, I only need it works.